# Check WeakReference Target Reference Count

Tags: c#, .net, weak-references

I know that if an object had no reference, and the GC cleared it, the object's WeakReference.Target property would return null,

But suppose the object has no strong reference, but the GC didnt clear it yet, is there anyway to check through its WeakReference whether or not it has any strong-references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - this is determined by whether the object has a GC root. The GC does not determine this until it runs.

Have a look at this MSDN magazine article ([part one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) and [part two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx)) for some more information about the GC in .Net.

** Update **
Thanks @Adriano for part 2 link.

Comment: Is there a chance that IsAlive would return false, but the WeakReference.Target would not be null? (in other words - does the IsAlive property being updated only when the GC runs?)

Comment: @sternr Sorry, comment about IsAlive property removed as I see you've already mentioned the null check of Target in your question. The two means of determining whether an object is alive or not will always give the same result.

Comment: Take a look to this nice article too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx